# Vertical Centering Table in Landscape Page

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to center this very wide and loooong table in a landscape page. I tried `\vfill` and couldn't do anything. Also tried to trim margins: nada. Anyone has an idea?

```
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}[p!]
    \centerline{
    \begin{tabular}{ll|ll|ll|ll|ll}\hline \hline
    loooooooooong table part with many lines\\
    loooooooooong table part with many lines\\
    loooooooooong table part with many lines\\
    loooooooooong table part with many lines\\
    loooooooooong table part with many lines\\
    loooooooooong table part with many lines\\
    loooooooooong table part with many lines\\
    loooooooooong table part with many lines\\
    \hline
    \legend\\
    \hline \hline
    \end{tabular}}
    \end{table}}
    \end{landscape}
    \pagestyle{plain}
```

Comment: Try adding \centering after \begin{table}[p!].

Comment: you can remove the `table` environment and the `\centerline` which are not doing anything useful, other than that hard to say as the example code isn't an example of the problem described, it is just a one column table with a 8 column preamble. Please make the example generate a problem table.

Comment: @Melian `\centering` will have no effect until `\centerline` is removed.

Comment: The only float on a page of floats should always be centered vertically.

Answer (score 1):

Some thing like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
% Or with the lscape package. 
%\usepackage{lscape}
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}[p!]\centering
    \begin{tabular}{ll|ll|ll|ll|ll}\hline \hline
    loooooooooong table part with many lines\\
    loooooooooong table part with many lines\\
    loooooooooong table part with many lines\\
    loooooooooong table part with many lines\\
    loooooooooong table part with many lines\\
    loooooooooong table part with many lines\\
    loooooooooong table part with many lines\\
    loooooooooong table part with many lines\\
    \hline
    legend\\
    \hline \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \end{landscape}
    \pagestyle{plain}

\end{document}
```